# How to make easier query and php value get?

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

Have a question about my code which isn't fast enough I believe. I've noticed that speed of all process got lower after injecting this code:

```
if (!empty($data['price1']) && !empty($data['price2']) && !empty($data['price3']) && !empty($data['price4']) && !empty($data['price5']) && !empty($data['price6']) && !empty($data['price7']) && !empty($data['price8']) && !empty($data['price9']) && !empty($data['price10'])) {
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT product_id from ".DB_PREFIX."product WHERE model='".$data['model']."' ");
        if($query->num_rows){
            $this->db->query("UPDATE ".DB_PREFIX."product_prices SET price='".$this->db->escape($data['price1'])."' WHERE product_id='".$query->row['product_id']."' and customer_group_id='2' ");      
            $this->db->query("UPDATE ".DB_PREFIX."product_prices SET price='".$this->db->escape($data['price2'])."' WHERE product_id='".$query->row['product_id']."' and customer_group_id='3' ");      
            $this->db->query("UPDATE ".DB_PREFIX."product_prices SET price='".$this->db->escape($data['price3'])."' WHERE product_id='".$query->row['product_id']."' and customer_group_id='4' ");      
            $this->db->query("UPDATE ".DB_PREFIX."product_prices SET price='".$this->db->escape($data['price4'])."' WHERE product_id='".$query->row['product_id']."' and customer_group_id='5' ");      
            $this->db->query("UPDATE ".DB_PREFIX."product_prices SET price='".$this->db->escape($data['price5'])."' WHERE product_id='".$query->row['product_id']."' and customer_group_id='6' ");      
            $this->db->query("UPDATE ".DB_PREFIX."product_prices SET price='".$this->db->escape($data['price6'])."' WHERE product_id='".$query->row['product_id']."' and customer_group_id='7' ");      
            $this->db->query("UPDATE ".DB_PREFIX."product_prices SET price='".$this->db->escape($data['price7'])."' WHERE product_id='".$query->row['product_id']."' and customer_group_id='8' ");      
            $this->db->query("UPDATE ".DB_PREFIX."product_prices SET price='".$this->db->escape($data['price8'])."' WHERE product_id='".$query->row['product_id']."' and customer_group_id='9' ");      
            $this->db->query("UPDATE ".DB_PREFIX."product_prices SET price='".$this->db->escape($data['price9'])."' WHERE product_id='".$query->row['product_id']."' and customer_group_id='10' ");     
            $this->db->query("UPDATE ".DB_PREFIX."product_prices SET price='".$this->db->escape($data['price10'])."' WHERE product_id='".$query->row['product_id']."' and customer_group_id='11' ");        

        }
        else
        {
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO ".DB_PREFIX."product_prices SET product_id='".$product_id."',price='".$data['price1']."',customer_group_id='2'");
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO ".DB_PREFIX."product_prices SET product_id='".$product_id."',price='".$data['price2']."',customer_group_id='3'");
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO ".DB_PREFIX."product_prices SET product_id='".$product_id."',price='".$data['price3']."',customer_group_id='4'");
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO ".DB_PREFIX."product_prices SET product_id='".$product_id."',price='".$data['price4']."',customer_group_id='5'");
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO ".DB_PREFIX."product_prices SET product_id='".$product_id."',price='".$data['price5']."',customer_group_id='6'");
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO ".DB_PREFIX."product_prices SET product_id='".$product_id."',price='".$data['price6']."',customer_group_id='7'");
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO ".DB_PREFIX."product_prices SET product_id='".$product_id."',price='".$data['price7']."',customer_group_id='8'");
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO ".DB_PREFIX."product_prices SET product_id='".$product_id."',price='".$data['price8']."',customer_group_id='9'");
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO ".DB_PREFIX."product_prices SET product_id='".$product_id."',price='".$data['price9']."',customer_group_id='10'");
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO ".DB_PREFIX."product_prices SET product_id='".$product_id."',price='".$data['price10']."',customer_group_id='11'");
        }
}
```

I'm not pro on php coding, trying to do my best, just I think there is probably faster way to update selected tables or if it's empty - insert new values. Tried to do in other way, like check every single data [price1], [price2] and etc, but that was much more slower, so tried in this way - still slow process going on.

Answer (score 0):

Use loop foreach

Something like this, but i don't know how you manage your "$product_id" and "customer_group_id"
I think you should not use same array for your prices and model

```
$query=$this->db->query("SELECT product_id from ".DB_PREFIX."product WHERE model='".$model."' ");

foreach($data as $key=>$value){
    $customer_group_id = $key+1;
    if($query->num_rows){
         $this->db->query("UPDATE ".DB_PREFIX."product_prices SET price='".$this->db->escape($value)."' WHERE product_id='".$query->row['product_id']."' and customer_group_id='".$customer_group_id."' ");  
    }else {
         $this->db->query("INSERT INTO ".DB_PREFIX."product_prices SET product_id='".$product_id."',price='".$value."',customer_group_id='".$customer_group_id."'");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, looks better, but struggling now with other issue:
`mysqli::real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in file` in code:

`public function escape($value) {
  return $this->connection->real_escape_string($value);
 }`

I'm not sure what's wrong with it by that array.
About model array, that's not important part I think, if I'm right - I can don't use it, it still updating by product_id , product_id used in whole file everywhere, so shouldn't be a problem that I believe.

Comment: you have this error because one of your data array value is an array. : $data['??'] = array(). You should check and conform your data array : $data['all keys'] = "string".

Comment: So probably I should make foreach for data formatters?
At the moment I have:

`if (isset($data['price']))                $data['price'] = $this->floatValue($data['price']);
  if (isset($data['price1']))      $data['price1'] = $this->floatValue($data['price1']);
  if (isset($data['price2']))      $data['price2'] = $this->floatValue($data['price2']);
  if (isset($data['price3']))      $data['price3'] = $this->floatValue($data['price3']); `

and that goes up to [price10], but that $value in query, should be defined somehow in right way, which I couldn't get :(

Comment: P.S. Price1; Price2; and etc. is selected values in opencart backend from uploaded file, and price1 always goes to customer_group+1 (if price1 then will be customer_group=2 and etc.), and in mysql tables there's customer_group_id column and price column

Comment: You can check what's value is not good in foreach with : if(is_array($value)){var_dump($key);} and yes you can use foreach almost everywhere you have redondant code

Comment: Still got no clue.. :D